# Discordjs bot crashes when pmed a command

Tags: discord, discord.js

Whenever a command is directly messaged to my bot, it crashes and the console logs

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of null

I'm new to js, so if you need me to paste any more code, please lmk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because your commands probably use properties from the `message.guild` object, which isn't available when a message is received through DMs.

You can add a check before the command to make sure it doesn't execute when `.guild` isn't available:

```js
if (!message.guild) return;
```